# How to join two tables with repeating entry in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i have two tables

```
*table1*
id(pk) name price
1  x1   y1
2  x2   y2

*table2*
id (fk) type(pk) title
1       t1       tit1
1       t2       tit2
2       t3       tit3
2       t4       tit4
2       t5       tit5
```

i like to join the tables alowing repeating of entries to obtain the result:

```
*result*
id  type title name price
1   t1   tit1  x1   y1
1   t2   tit2  x1   y1
2   t3   tit3  x2   y2
2   t4   tit4  x2   y2
5   t5   tit5  x2   y2
```

Comment: The last row is having id 5. Where did it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple join does this...

```
select
*
from
table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot it's easy i just miss somme lines of codes,  can you tell me how to cancel repeating lines in a table ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```